# signalr not working with https Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Tags: websocket, signalr, angular6, signalr-hub

I have backend that I use signalr for websockets. When client and backend were on http, everything worked.

Then I switched to https. Now I see this errors in browser:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com/chatHub?id=mKk-uj0P0_7WsLFXjXhskA' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

POST https://example.com/chatHub?id=HSwLlWtJGpBP0Dib6sHobQ 404 (Not Found)
```

The weirdes thing is, that even I see this errors, on Edge chat is working (on chrome and firefox not).

What is going on here and how can I fix that?
client is angular 6 (@aspnet/signalr for hub connection)
backend is dotnet

Edit: I forgot to mention, I have backend and client proxied with nginx.

Comment: I had this issue because of the bad reconnect logic I had. You might wanna share your reconnect logic

Comment: There was no reconnect logic. I sometimes experience random disconnects, seems like it is not stable for me.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was issue with nginx.

```
proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header  Connection "Upgrade";
```

on server nginx.conf fixed issue